# git diff current directory as default

Tags: git

git diff by default  give me the diff of all repo , but when  I'm working in a directory I don't want see diff of others directories , `git diff .` is solution 
but I'd like  set it by default like svn , it is possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the behavior of a core git operation like 'diff' is discouraged (any script you run that is expecting `git diff` to report on all modified files will be broken).  You would be better off creating an alias like diffpwd or similar that did what you want.

Comment: and about the question, any answer ?

Comment: Andrew means answer = try `alias diffpwd='git diff .'` and then just use `diffpwd` in place of `git diff .`

Comment: Git doesn't allow you to override built-ins with aliases.  Your only option would be something crazy like a wrapper script named 'git' that looked at arg 1 and then called real git with '.' appended if arg1 == diff